# Internal energy in classical and quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics

What is the difference between classical and quantum mechanics of rotational, translational and vibrational energies?

Comment: yes and it is said that energy in quantum mechanics is discrete but maybe there is another difference

Comment: Energy in quantum mechanics is not discrete. The energy levels of rotational and vibrational states are (almost) discrete. Translation in free space causes a continuous spectrum and momentum is not quantized unless there is some external potential.

Comment: This question is too vague. Are you getting at the general differences between classical and quantum observables, or at any specific difference that you have reason to believe arises in the case of energies?